# Plugin/Gem to get Rails 3 style UJS in Rails 2.3.x?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unobtrusive-javascript, jrails

I have a new application starting that's using Rails 2.3.8 for stability concerns and gem compatibility, however we'd like to begin being conscious of Unobtrusive JavaScript by implementing the Rails 3 style UJS in this application.  Is there any existing plugin/gem that backports this feature?

We are currently using the [jrails](http://github.com/aaronchi/jrails) gem to swap jQuery for Prototype, as it is better suited to our needs.  Is there an easy way to integrate jQuery with Rails 3 style UJS in a Rails 2.3.x application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not a plugin, but still quite useful, and both solutions use jquery:

1. http://andrewcox.org/post/507032751/rails-3-0-unobtrusive-ajax-in-rails-2-3-x
2. https://github.com/aeden/unobtrusive-jquery-example